# Logstash fails to connect to rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to setup a logstash configuration to push lines from a file to rabbitmq. I installed both logstash 2.1.1 and rabbit 3.6.0 on my local machine to test it. the output configuration is:

```
output {
    rabbitmq {
            exchange => "test_exchange"
            key => "test"
            exchange_type => "direct"
            host => "127.0.0.1"
            port => "15672"
            user => "logstash"
            password => "logstashpassword"
        }
}
```

But when I now start logstash it fails to startup with the following error (the output is only shown when logstash is started in debug mode):

```
Worker threads expected: 4, worker threads started: 4 {:level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"186", :method=>"start_filters"}
Connecting to RabbitMQ. Settings: {:vhost=>"/", :host=>"127.0.0.1", :port=>15672, :user=>"logstash", :automatic_recovery=>true, :pass=>"logstashpassword", :timeout=>0, :heartbeat=>0} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin_mixins/rabbitmq_connection.rb", :line=>"135", :method=>"connect"}
The error reported is: 

com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(com/rabbitmq/utility/BlockingCell.java:77)
com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(com/rabbitmq/utility/BlockingCell.java:111)
com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(com/rabbitmq/utility/BlockingValueOrException.java:37)
com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(com/rabbitmq/client/impl/AMQChannel.java:367)
com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(com/rabbitmq/client/impl/AMQConnection.java:293)
com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.java:621)
com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.java:648)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:606)
RUBY.new_connection_impl(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.11.0-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:505)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281)
RUBY.converting_rjc_exceptions_to_ruby(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.11.0-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:467)
RUBY.new_connection_impl(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.11.0-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:500)
RUBY.initialize(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.11.0-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:136)
RUBY.connect(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.11.0-java/lib/march_hare/session.rb:109)
RUBY.connect(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/march_hare-2.11.0-java/lib/march_hare.rb:20)
RUBY.connect(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-mixin-rabbitmq_connection-2.2.0-java/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/rabbitmq_connection.rb:137)
RUBY.connect!(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-mixin-rabbitmq_connection-2.2.0-java/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/rabbitmq_connection.rb:94)
RUBY.register(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-rabbitmq-3.0.6-java/lib/logstash/outputs/rabbitmq.rb:40)
org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)
RUBY.start_outputs(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.1-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:192)
RUBY.run(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.1-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:102)
RUBY.execute(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.1-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:165)
RUBY.run(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.1-java/lib/logstash/runner.rb:90)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281)
RUBY.run(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.1.1-java/lib/logstash/runner.rb:95)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281)
RUBY.initialize(/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.22/lib/stud/task.rb:24)
java.lang.Thread.run(java/lang/Thread.java:745)
```

And then logstash "crashes" i.e. stops. Does anyone know if that has to do with the config of logstash or is it a problem in rabbitMQ setup?

Thanks in advance.
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Found my error the port for rabbitMQ has to be `5672` not `15672`.